# Prove that $G$ contains a subgroup $H_i$ for each $i\in\Bbb Z$ with $\dots\subset H_{−2}\subset H_{−1}\subset H_0\subset H_1\subset\dots?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $$ be the group generated by the matrices $=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, where the group operation is matrix multiplication.

> Prove that $$ contains a subgroup $_$ for each $\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
>   $$ \cdots \subset H_{-2}\subset H_{-1} \subset H_0 \subset H_1 \subset \cdots$$

So this is all that is given and i'm not sure where to start from this question. I know that $ABA^{-1}$ = $B^{2}$. From this we can replace *A* with $A^2$ and so on but i am not sure how i would prove this. Can someone help please?

Comment: In the future, please typset the mathematics of your question with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), as @SMA.D kindly did for you.

Comment: Also, you have not asked a question, you have only made a demand for a proof, which might not be well received on this site. Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on how to ask a good question, and more particularly the subtopic [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for ways to improve your question by adding some additional context: include your work on this problem; tell us what you've tried; and so on.

Comment: Well, you've found the start of a pattern. Have you tried extrapolating this to find a general form for your conjugate matrices, and then proving it via induction?

Comment: Im not quite sure how to find the general form. I think once i get that i may be able to prove it by induction

Comment: What you wrote is wrong. $A^{-1}BA$ is $B$ with the bottom left entry replaced by $2$., whereas $ABA^{-1}$ is $B$ with the bottom left entry replaced by $1/2$.

Comment: @mrlocal try conjugating by $A$, $A^2$, $A^3$,... until a pattern starts to emerge (it may not emerge though).

Comment: @DerekHolt i think you may have done something wrong. For _$A^{-1}$_ i got  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. Hence when i did _$A^{-1}B$_ i got  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$. Therefore _$A^{-1}BA$_ =  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Comment: @user1729 By doing so i get a similar matrix to _B_ but the top left entry will always be $(\frac{1}{2})^i$ for all conjugation by _$A^i$_

Comment: The matrix $B$ in your question has an entry $1$ in the lower left position not in the upper right position.

Comment: @Derek I see that now. Thank you. I’m not sure what to do for this question now.

Comment: Try $H_i = \langle A^i B A^{-i} \rangle$ (the infinite cyclic subgroup generated by the matrix $A^i B A^{-i}$).

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. I managed to get a general formula of $A^{i}BA^{-i}$ = $B^{2^{i}}$ for any _i_. Im pretty sure its simple from here but how would this show subgroup $H_i$ such that ⋯⊂$_{−2}$⊂$_{−1}$⊂$_0$⊂$_1$⊂⋯

Comment: If you can show that $H_0 \subset H_1$, then all of the other containments follow immediately by conjugating by a power of $A$.

Comment: @DerekHolt i'm not exactly sure how you can show that $H_0$ ⊂ $H_1$

Comment: That is really not very hard. What exactly are the elements of $H_0 = \langle B \rangle$? Then what are the elements of $H_1 = \langle B^2 \rangle$?