# Prove group G has a subgroup $H_i$ where group operation is multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $$ be the group generated by the matrices $=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$, where the group operation is matrix multiplication.

> Prove that $$ contains a subgroup $_$ for each $\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
>   $$ \cdots \subset H_{-2}\subset H_{-1} \subset H_0 \subset H_1 \subset \cdots$$

So this is all that is given and i'm not sure where to start from this question. I know that $ABA^{-1}$ is just B with the bottom right replaced by $1/2$. From this we can replace *A* with $A^2$ and so on but i am not sure how i would prove this. Can someone help please?

Comment: I assume the subgroups must be distinct?

Comment: This is just a repeat of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597455/), which has been closed.

Comment: @GregoryGrant thats right. Each groups must be distinct